# Как работать в Geany с Python 2 и 3 на Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, python-2.x, geany

Добрый день! У меня Ubuntu 12.04, изучаю Python. Установил через консоль обе версии поставил `Geany` и `Sublime 2`, вообще работаю с `Geany`. Но проблема в том, что он видит интерпретатор питона только 2.7, а 3-го не видит и настроить его не могу. А мне для Django надо 2-й а для PyQt нужен 3-й питон. Как его заставить понимать что мне надо? Спасибо большое ...

Answer (score 2):

Geany > Сборка > Установить команды сборки. Там в "Выполнить" и "Скомпилировать" заменить *python* на *python3*.

Answer (score 1):

я обычно использую virtual env, когда мне нужна специфическая версия интерпретатора и/или питонобиблиотек

Comment: Попробуем тоже использовать такое ...

Answer (score 1):

все просто как дважды два.
 1. Если вы можете из консоли запустить интерпретатор 3 питона (он скорее всего у вас запускается как python3 в то время как 2 питон просто python) то все что вам нужно это только поменять название запускаемого интерпретатора в настройках geany (в Арче у меня у самого стоит обе версии питона 2 и 3, но основной там 3, а 2 запускаю как python2)
 2. А если они перекрывают друг друга (то есть то что последний портит файлы предыдущего при установке) то тогда да, только через виртуальное окружение, но это навряд ли....

Comment: В Ubuntu 14.04 (да и в 12.04) python2  и 3 прекрасно существуют вместе ничуть друг-другу не мешая. Ответ верен, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

В генту с этим проще=) Посмотри тут [habr](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/9934/) , кроме всего советуют посмотреть [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю !

Comment: а что принципиально отличается касательно этого вопроса в убунте и генте? :D

Comment: В Gentoo есть такие концепции, как slots и USE-флаги. 

Слоты позволяют одновременно устанавливать и использовать разные версии одного и того-же пакета. А use-флаги позволяют задать дополнительные требования при сборке пакета. 

Например, если для `PyQt` в `USE` будут указаны флаги `python2_7`, `python3_2` и `pypy1_9`, то при установке этого пакета с зависимостями подтянутся все три версии питона и модули `PyQt` скомпилируются для всех трех интерперетаторов.

Comment: это всё, конечно, хорошо, только вот как относится к тематике вопроса? насколько я понимаю, у топикстартера стоит проблема не в том, как собрать что-то с поддержкой разных версий питона, а в том, как использовать специфическую версию интерпретатора в проекте

Comment: Согласен с первым комментарием @actionless. Человек не стал бы спрашивать, если бы ему не нужно было бы это ПО.